# FOSJSRoutingBundle - Routing.generate doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm facing a bit of a trouble with the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html) in Symfony4 when trying to load a new template from my Javascript file.

I followed the instructions over [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html).

The route I want to call is as follow :

```
 /**
  * @Route("/", name="homepage", options={"expose" = true})
  */
  public function homepage()
  {
     return $this->render('home.html.twig');
  }
```

When

```
 Routing.generate('homepage');
 alert("Finished!");
```

in my Javascript file gets called, the alert gets displayed and nothing else happens. I should probably add that I'm obviously not on the homepage when this gets called.

However, if I purposefully misspell the name of the Route or if I call a route that has not been exposed via

```
options={"expose" = true}
```

I do get an error :

```
Error: The route "misspelled_route" does not exist. 2 router.js:220:27
```

and no alert gets displayed, which leads me to believe that I followed the instructions on the Symfony website correctly (?).

Am I missing something obvious or poorly using the bundle ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Did you run `php bin/console fos:js-routing:dump`? Then `php bin/console cache:clear`?

Comment: I hadn't, but I just did and it still doesn't work. Thanks however for the suggestion !

Comment: Open up the console developer tools of your browser, and trigger again the js action. Maybe some sort of error will be displayed there. If not, maybe your js script is the problem.

Comment: What do you expect ? Routing.generate just format an url, it return a string. What do you want exactly ? Make a redirection ?

Comment: Oh yes, the error I mentionned in my post is displayed in the console of the browser (Firefox). There's no error displayed there when the name of the route is correct, however.

----

Gonna Edit that for pbenard : Yes, I'd like to make a redirection. I didn't get the fact that it just returned a string, to be honest, that's not what the Symfony page seemed to imply, but I must have read it wrong, then !

Comment: alert("Finished!"); window.location.href = Routing.generate('homepage');

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly @pbenard !
DanCostinel, Thanks a lot for your help :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm supposed to answer my own question like this, but if anybody has the same problem when following the Symfony website's instruction on FOSJsRoutingBundle :

Routing.generate returns a String. If you're like me and want the page to redirect, you can use

```
window.location.href = Routing.generate('your_route_name');
```

Thanks to pbenard for this !